# python pandas empty Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, finance

You need these 2 files for the short script:

- [file 1](https://www.file-upload.net/download-12647206/djia.csv.html)
- [file 2](https://www.file-upload.net/download-12647207/PreisMoatStanley2013.dat.html)

The problem is to get the index to Date. My index is always empty

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
 
paper = pd.read_csv('PreisMoatStanley2013.dat',
                    delimiter = ' ',
                    parse_dates=[0,1,100,101])
 
 
 
data = pd.DataFrame({'GoogleWE': paper['Google End Date'],
                    'debt': paper['debt'].astype(np.float64),
                    'DJIADate': paper['DJIA Date'],
                    'DJIAClose': paper['DJIA Closing Price']
                    .astype(np.float64)})
data.set_index('DJIADate')
print paper [:5]
 
import quandl
#api_key = open('quandl_key.txt','r').read()
 
djia = pd.read_csv("djia.csv", index_col=0)
 
print djia[:3]
 
djia_closes = djia['Close'].reset_index()
djia_closes.set_index('Date')
print djia_closes[:3]
#s152
data = pd.merge(data, djia_closes,
left_on='DJIADate', right_on='Date')
data.drop(['DJIADate'], inplace=True, axis=1)
data = data.set_index('Date') # Problem seems to be here
 
print data[:3]
```

Shell message:

> Empty DataFrame
>
> Columns: [DJIAClose, GoogleWE, debt, Close]
>
> Index: []

How it should looks like:

```
Date       /DJIAClose /GoogleWE  /debt /Close
2004-01-12 10485.18   2004-01-10 0.21  10485.2
2004-01-20 10528.66   2004-01-17 0.21  10528.7
2004-01-26 10702.51   2004-01-24 0.21  10702.5
```

Data from `data`:

```
  DJIAClose DJIADate   GoogleWE   debt
0 10485.18  2004-01-12 2004-01-10 0.210000
1 10528.66  2004-01-20 2004-01-17 0.210000
2 10702.51  2004-01-26 2004-01-24 0.210000 
3 10499.18  2004-02-02 2004-01-31 0.213333
4 10579.03  2004-02-09 2004-02-07 0.200000
5 10714.88  2004-02-17 2004-02-14 0.203333
6 10609.62  2004-02-23 2004-02-21 0.200000
7 10678.14  2004-03-01 2004-02-28 0.200000
8 10529.48  2004-03-08 2004-03-06 0.196667
```

Data from `djia_closes`

```
Date       Close 
2004-01-02 10409.9
2004-01-08 10592.4
2004-01-09 10458.9
2004-01-12 10485.2
2004-01-13 10427.2
2004-01-14 10538.4
2004-01-20 10528.7
2004-01-26 10702.5
```

data.head()

```
  DJIAClose   DJIADate   GoogleWE  debt
0 10485.18 2004-01-12 2004-01-10 0.210000
1 10528.66 2004-01-20 2004-01-17 0.210000
2 10702.51 2004-01-26 2004-01-24 0.210000
3 10499.18 2004-02-02 2004-01-31 0.213333
4 10579.03 2004-02-09 2004-02-07 0.200000
```

djia_closes.head()

```
  Date    Close
0 2004-01-02 10409.9
1 2004-01-05 10544.1
2 2004-01-06 10538.7
3 2004-01-07 10529.0
4 2004-01-08 10592.4
```

Comment: cant format the output exactly..

Comment: You have a fair amount of code here - any chance you can reduce it to a smaller section that's causing your problem?  Can you remove some of the intermediate code between loading the file and the error?

Comment: I think the intresting part is the data=pd.merge...
It merge the data but without any result. Maybe you should need to know, both file use a date but different names for it (#1 file= date #2 file = DJIADate). The point is he cant connect it  together like the example says.

Comment: Can you confirm that `data` and `djia_closes` have content before `pd.merge()`?  Can you confirm that they actually have overlapping dates?
  Also, note that you use `set_index()` but you don't assign it to the `df` or use `inplace=True`, so the index isn't actually being set.

Comment: yeah they actually have data inside and some of same have same dates.

Comment: For us to provide an answer, you're probably going to need to reconstruct your question so that it has a little sample of both dataframes (say, the first five lines), and just enough code to make the problem occur.

Comment: it tooks me ages to format the output, but im done tehre it is. Not all data are matching but some. So i skipped some data.

Comment: I'm sorry it took a while - all I'm looking for are the contents of `data.head()` and `djia_closes.head()` right before you perform the `pd.merge( ... )`.  Also, what happens if you try `df = data.merge(djia_closes, left_on=True, right_on=True)`?

Comment: is there any secret to edit the datas without getting every time an error message like: its look like code but...

Comment: sorry but i cant format the last part correctly....i dont get it how it works.
data.merge(djia_closes, left_on=True, right_on=True) throws an KeyError:True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `parse_dates` option when reading in the `paper` csv, but not when reading in the `djia` csv.  That might be causing your problem - the "date" column `data` is a datetime object, but in `djia_close` the date is just a string.  So there aren't any matches, which is why you're getting an empty dataframe when you merge them.

Try removing `parse_dates` from `read_csv` and see what happens, or try converting both date columns to datetime objects before merging.

Comment: Hi ASGM, thanks for your help! 
I removed the parse_dates line and it works now exactly. Correct me if i'm wrong , the parse_dates function convert a string to an datetime object?

Comment: Yes, that's what `parse_dates` does, but you were only doing it to one of your dataframes, so they didn't match.